# Component not showing on page

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I got an `Angular2` project that was developed by a different person and I need to run it. When I do, using `npm start` I get the server to run but the component, called `my-app` is not rendering on the page.

This is the `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href='/'>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading......</my-app> 
  </body>
</html>
```

This is `app.components.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = '';
    isProd:boolean;
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private  router: Router) {
        this.isProd = false; 
}
```

In the `template` for `my-app`, which is `app/app.component.html` I put a simple `div` for testing:

```
<div><h1>app components</h1></div>
```

When running this I can see the `Loading.....` which is in `index.html` but not the contents of `app/app.component.html`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your console for any errors.

Comment: I get a c3.css not found.

Comment: What is AuthenticationService? I had the same issues few days ago, I had to add providers in @Componet, and it fixed the problem( e.g. `providers: [AuthenticationService]` )

Comment: AuthenticationService is just a service inside the app. Nothing much in it. I tried to add providers: [AuthenticationService, Router], but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see if you are loading angular and your transpiled ts anywhere in index.html. You need to load all required dependeny for run angular2 app in index.html and allso your transpiled ts.

> Note:- you need to put base tag after all you link to load css.

```
 <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
        <link href="c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <base href='/'>
```

Comment: how do you mean load all required dependencies? I'm looking at this example, https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview and there's nothing in the index.html file that seems to do the load angular task.

Comment: @Eddy I do not see any angular loading in this plunker? [take  look at this seed](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed)